# What does the clearfix class do in css?

Tags: html, css, clearfix

I've seen `div` tags use a `clearfix` class when it's child `divs` use the `float` property. The clearfix class looks like this:

```
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
.clearfix {
    display: block;
}
```

I found that if I don't use `clearfix` when I use the `bottom-border` property, the border would show above the child `divs`. Can someone explain what the clearfix class does? Also, why are there two `display` properties? That seems very strange to me. I am especially curious about what the `content:'.'` means.

Thanks,G

Answer (score 123, accepted):

## How floats work

When floating elements exist on the page, non-floating elements *wrap around* the floating elements, similar to how text goes around a picture in a newspaper. From a document perspective (the *original purpose* of HTML), this is how floats work.

## `float` vs `display:inline`

Before the invention of `display:inline-block`, websites use `float` to set elements beside each other. `float` is preferred over `display:inline` since with the latter, you can't set the element's dimensions (width and height) as well as vertical paddings (top and bottom) - which floated elements can do since they're treated as block elements.

## Float problems

The main problem is that we're using `float` against its intended purpose.

Another is that while `float` allows side-by-side block-level elements, *floats do not impart shape to its container*. It's like `position:absolute`, where the element is "taken out of the layout". For instance, when an empty container contains a floating 100px x 100px `<div>`, the `<div>` will not impart 100px in height to the container.

Unlike `position:absolute`, it affects the content that surrounds it. Content after the floated element will "wrap" around the element. It starts by rendering beside it and then below it, like how newspaper text would flow around an image.

## Clearfix to the rescue

What *clearfix* does is to force content after the floats or the container containing the floats to render below it. There are a lot of versions for clear-fix, but it got its name from the version that's commonly being used - the one that uses the CSS property `clear`.

## Examples

[Here are several ways to do clearfix](http://jsfiddle.net/gZa64/138/) , depending on the browser and use case. One only needs to know how to use the `clear` property in CSS and how floats render in each browser in order to achieve a perfect cross-browser clear-fix.

## What you have

Your provided style is a form of clearfix with backwards compatibility. [I found an article](http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/06/new-clearfix-hack/) about this clearfix. It turns out, it's an OLD clearfix - still catering the old browsers. There is a newer, cleaner version of it in the article also. Here's the breakdown:

- The first clearfix you have appends an invisible pseudo-element, which is styled `clear:both`, between the target element and the next element. This forces the pseudo-element to render below the target, and the next element below the pseudo-element.
- The second one appends the style `display:inline-block` which is not supported by earlier browsers. inline-block is like inline but gives you some properties that block elements, like width, height as well as vertical padding. This was targeted for IE-MAC.
- This was the reapplication of `display:block` due to IE-MAC rule above. This rule was "hidden" from IE-MAC.

All in all, these 3 rules keep the `.clearfix` working cross-browser, with old browsers in mind.

Comment: Won't the final `display:block` override `display:inline-block` on all browsers, including those that support `inline-block`?

Comment: edited my answer. it's not for the last element. it's for an empty element after it. sometimes you see others add `<div class="clearfix"></div>` after the last floated element to emulate the "blank content" of `:after`. this is for older browsers.

Comment: Your explanation is well detailed.But why dot means blank?

Comment: it's just dummy content, hence "blank". you won't really see it because of `height:0` and `visibility:hidden`. it does not impart anything in the design other than the clearing.

Comment: @Joseph i agree with your answer but i am curious to know the structure (HTML) on which above(clearfix) class applied. Can you elaborate so any one who read this question in future can easily understand. Please and thanks in advance.

Comment: updated my answer. check the fiddle and the article for more details.

Comment: I must add on top of your answer that the same effect (of making the parent be as large as its content - even if the content is floating) can be done also by adding `overflow: hidden` to the parent - without adding any HTML (not even the clearfix)

Comment: @YaronU. You'll encounter problems if the content has shadows (see updated demo). `overflow:hidden` will clip the shadows if they try to overflow the container. Here, the `:after` or the additional element clearfix solution is better.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer that right :), I just mentioned it so people can use it when possible - which is in most cases. anyway, thanks for the clarification

Comment: Principally, if I use 'inline-block' and I know my targeted browsers all support it - I wouldn't have any need for 'clearfix', right?

Comment: Your first statement is misleading. "_non-floating elements wrap around the floating elements_" -- Only the text wrap around the floating elements not any non-floating element. A `div` will start from the left of the page as usual because it can't see the floating elements(out of document flow).

Answer (score 19):

When an element, such as a `div` is `floated`, its parent container no longer considers its height, i.e.

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="child" style="float:left;height:40px;"> Hi</div>
</div>
```

The parent container will not be be 40 pixels tall by default. This causes a lot of weird little quirks if you're using these containers to structure layout.

So the `clearfix` class that various frameworks use fixes this problem by making the parent container "acknowledge" the contained elements.

Day to day, I normally just use frameworks such as 960gs, Twitter Bootstrap for laying out and not bothering with the exact mechanics.

**Can read more here**

http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Comment: Thanks!I use Bootstrap too...

Answer (score 7):

`clearfix` is the same as `overflow:hidden`. Both clear floated children of the parent, but `clearfix` will not cut off the element which overflow to it's `parent`.
It also works in IE8 & above.

There is no need to define `"."` in content & .clearfix. Just write like this:

```
.clr:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent clr"></div>
```

Read these links for more

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/,

[What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)