# Bootstrap / CSS - why is .clearfix needed here

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, clearfix

I had an issue while trying to place some `<input/>` elements in a fixed-positioned DIV with Bootstrap 3. It seemed that the container DIV grew in width to accommodate the inputs (which were inside `col-*` containers) for no apparent reason. Here is a demo code:

```
    <div class="dropdown-menu" style="top: 10px; left: 400px; position: fixed; display: block;">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="radio">
            <label> <input type="radio" name="st" value="0">Bark</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
            <label> <input type="radio" name="st" value="1">Roll over</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
            <label> <input type="radio" name="st" value="2">Find bone and bury it underground</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 whyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy">
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is how the above looks with:

[image: Too much width]

And this is without the inputs:

[image: Normal Thing]

After checking widths and min-widths, I discovered that only using `.clearfix` between all `col-*` elements fixed the problem, like so:

```
    <div class="dropdown-menu" style="top: 10px; left: 400px; position: fixed; display: block;">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="radio">
            <label> <input type="radio" name="st" value="0">Bark</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
            <label> <input type="radio" name="st" value="1">Roll over</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
            <label> <input type="radio" name="st" value="2">Find bone and bury it underground</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <i class="clearfix" />
        <div class="col-xs-12 whyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy">
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <i class="clearfix" />
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <i class="clearfix" />
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <i class="clearfix" />
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is how the above looks:

[image: Fixed with clearfix]

One of these `.clearfix`-es to be missing and I get terrible container sizes.

I have tried turning to theory by reading about `.clearfix`, e.g. from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9543569/964053 but, again, I do not see what `.clearfix` changes in this case.

I mean, all elements/content in my case are already floating. Why is the container growing like that and how does `.clearfix` manage to fix it? The referenced answer says `floats do not impart shape to its container` and `What clearfix does is to force content after the floats or the container containing the floats to render below it`. If in my case the floating elements themselves do no cause the container to grow, what the hack does this? The spaces between them?

Is there a better fix for this than using clearfix elements all over the place?

**UPDATE :**

Hm... It seems there is something invalid in the HTML of my solution code in the 2nd code snippet. It's the self closing `<i>` elements. That was fixing the problem in Bootply but not outside of it. Here is what I was getting in Bootply:

[image: bootply bug]

Hmm... So, I guess I still have no solution to this (at least not one that requires hacks). Any ideas on how to solve this the bootstrap way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall width of the `input` container is `col-xs-12`. So they will try and use up that 12 column space. So you can use a smaller col-*-# on the the parent:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <input class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <input class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <input class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <input class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

However, you might have a bigger problem in how your columns are set up. For example, a column `col-xs-12` as a direct descendant of another `col-xs-12` is redundant. You should also be using `.row` containers.

See the [boostrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic) on grids.

Also, never wrap your block level elements like `<div>` with inline elements like `<i>` **unless** their display property is set to `inline-block` or `block`. Or your page will render with unexpected results.