# How to display Bootstrap grid view with elements inlined in the same block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap "list grid  products view" sample and grid elements are displayed fine when description and picture height is the same.

Working sample: `https://codepen.io/ajaypatelaj/pen/zIBjJ`

Problem comes in when description, price and picture are of different height and do not display elements in line:

```
https://codepen.io/getkitchendeal/pen/gRgGeG
```

i tried to fix with=>

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to fix this, but it's ugly. It's called the clearfix hack.
Check out this thread [What does the clearfix class do in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543541/what-does-the-clearfix-class-do-in-css)

Comment: Thank you, i ended up using clearfix class and adding row class dynamically 
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211799/angular-ng-repeat-add-bootstrap-row-every-3-or-4-cols)

Answer (score 0):

What I would do here is fix min-height for each block for grid system.

Create a new css rule:

```
.list-group-item .thumbnail {
    min-height: inherit;
}
```

And add another one in .thumbnail

```
.thumbnail {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    min-height: 400px; #new rule
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution did work and i have updated the codepen code:(https://codepen.io/getkitchendeal/pen/gRgGeG)