# parent element not following child element

Tags: html, css, css-float

When we set up a parent element, and increment the contents of the child elements, shouldn't the size of the parents automatically scale to fit the child?

In contrast, the parent having applied the css properties, such as background given to it, does not scale for the parent. Here is my attempt to creating a 3 column simple layout, and the parent not scaling, and hence the border bottom is not being applied:

[REPL.IT](https://repl.it/KXgW)

As you can see, the contents are overflowing the parent and everything is not enclosed within the parent. How should I fix this?

Comment: First of all, please go read [ask]. Relevant code belongs directly into your question, so please edit it accordingly.

Comment: And then, you want to go research how to _enclose floated elements_.

Comment: @lumio, Header?

Comment: Oh he deleted his comment. Sorry :)

Comment: @lumio, do you know how to select an element by id within an element by id? Ex: a div with id "x" is enclosing a div with an element 'y', and I want to get ahold of 'y' by ID. How do I do that? (I didn't want to make another post)

Comment: Better make another post though :) but why not giving y a class or id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is a clearfix on your `#bodytext` because all your content floats.

Add the following line to your `#bodytext`:

```
#bodytext{
  overflow: auto;
}
```

For a better understanding, why you need a clearfix, [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9543569/881032).

Comment: I added a link with some further explanation to it :)

Comment: that's great. (It appears I can only accept  the answer after 8 min.)

Comment: No worries haha :D but thanks if you are going to accept it.

Comment: @kukkuz just did :)

Answer (score 1):

You have not properly *cleared* the `floats` - add `overflow: hidden` to `bodyText` or add an `after` element that uses `clear: left`:

```
#bodytext:after{
  clear: left;
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
```

See demo below:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "handlee";
  src: url("handlee.ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "berkshirestyle";
  src: url("berkshire.ttf");
}

body {
  background-image: url("glass.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#FirstHeader {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  padding-left: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 70px;
  color: rgb(122, 38, 0);
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-family: handlee;
  font-style: italic;
}

#bodytext {
  padding: 30px;
  font-family: berkshirestyle, cursive;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #BCBCBC;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#bodytext:after{
  clear: left;
  content: '';
  display: block;
}

#bodytext {
  clear: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid red;
  background-color: red;
}

#bodytext div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  float: left;
}

form {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="FirstHeader">Coffes here</h1>
<img src="coffee.png" id="Coffee" alt="coffee image" width="100" height="125" />


<div id="bodytext">

  <div id="FirstParagraph">
    Duis maximus enim in vestibulum posuere. Nullam tempor, est in rutrum ullamcorper, Vivamus ut mi orci. Donec ut ipsum in nisl elementum posuere mollis id massa. Cras mattis felis est, a varius nisl euismod ac. Mauris cursus sed nulla in viverra. Duis
    maximus enim in vestibulum posuere. Nullam tempor, est in rutrum ullamcorper, purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus est. Nulla vel tortor id ligula consequat fringilla dignissim a sem. Duis eget risus
    vel est ullamcorper auctor. Aliquam vel ex in leo suscipit condimentum sed vitae leo. In porta eget augue eu porta. Pellentesque tellus eros, consequat vel aliquet id, consectetur a ante. Vestibulum sit amet ligula faucibus ligula auctor pretium non
    vel arcu.<br> purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus Vivamus ut mi orci. Donec ut ipsum in nisl elementum posuere mollis id massa. Cras mattis felis est, a varius nisl euismod ac. Mauris cursus sed
    nulla in viverra. Duis maximus enim in vestibulum posuere. Nullam tempor, est in rutrum ullamcorper, purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus est. Nulla vel tortor id ligula consequat fringilla dignissim
    a sem. Duis eget risus vel est ullamcorper auctor. Aliquam vel ex in leo suscipit condimentum sed vitae leo. In porta eget augue eu porta. Pellentesque tellus eros, consequat vel aliquet id, consectetur a ante. Vestibulum sit amet ligula faucibus
    ligula auctor pretium non vel arcu.purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus Vivamus ut mi orci. Donec ut ipsum in nisl elementum posuere mollis id massa. Cras mattis felis est, a varius nisl euismod ac.
    Mauris cursus sed nulla in viverra. Duis maximus enim in vestibulum posuere. Nullam tempor, est in rutrum ullamcorper, purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus est. Nulla vel tortor id ligula consequat fringilla
    dignissim a sem. Duis eget risus vel est ullamcorper auctor. Aliquam vel ex in leo suscipit condimentum sed vitae leo. In porta eget augue eu porta. Pellentesque tellus eros, consequat vel aliquet id, consectetur a ante. Vestibulum sit amet ligula
    faucibus ligula auctor pretium non vel arcu.
  </div>


  <div id="SecondParagraph">
    purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus Vivamus ut mi orci. Donec ut ipsum in nisl elementum posuere mollis id massa. Cras mattis felis est, a varius nisl euismod ac. Mauris cursus sed nulla in viverra. Duis
    maximus enim in vestibulum posuere. Nullam tempor, est in rutrum ullamcorper, purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus est. Nulla vel tortor id ligula consequat fringilla dignissim a sem. Duis eget risus
    vel est ullamcorper auctor. Aliquam vel ex in leo suscipit condimentum sed vitae leo. In porta eget augue eu porta. Pellentesque tellus eros, consequat vel aliquet id, consectetur a ante. Vestibulum sit amet ligula faucibus ligula auctor pretium non
    vel arcu.
    <br/> purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus Vivamus ut mi orci. Donec ut ipsum in nisl elementum posuere mollis id massa. Cras mattis felis est, a varius nisl euismod ac. Mauris cursus sed nulla in viverra.
    Duis maximus enim in vestibulum posuere. Nullam tempor, est in rutrum ullamcorper, purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus est. Nulla vel tortor id ligula consequat fringilla dignissim a sem. Duis eget
    risus vel est ullamcorper auctor. Aliquam vel ex in leo suscipit condimentum sed vitae leo. In porta eget augue eu porta. Pellentesque tellus eros, consequat vel aliquet id, consectetur a ante. Vestibulum sit amet ligula faucibus ligula auctor pretium
    non vel arcu.purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus Vivamus ut mi orci. Donec ut ipsum in nisl elementum posuere mollis id massa. Cras mattis felis est, a varius nisl euismod ac. Mauris cursus sed nulla
    in viverra. Duis maximus enim in vestibulum posuere. Nullam tempor, est in rutrum ullamcorper, purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus est. Nulla vel tortor id ligula consequat fringilla dignissim a sem.
    Duis eget risus vel est ullamcorper auctor. Aliquam vel ex in leo suscipit condimentum sed vitae leo. In porta eget augue eu porta. Pellentesque tellus eros, consequat vel aliquet id, consectetur a ante. Vestibulum sit amet ligula faucibus ligula
    auctor pretium non vel arcu.
  </div>

  <div id="ThirdParagraph">
    eget augue eu porta. Pellentesque tellus eros, consequat vel aliquet id, consectetur a ante. Vivamus ut mi orci. Donec ut ipsum in nisl elementum posuere mollis id massa. Cras mattis felis est, a varius nisl euismod ac. Mauris cursus sed nulla in viverra.
    Duis maximus enim in vestibulum posuere. Nullam tempor, est in rutrum ullamcorper, purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus est. Nulla vel tortor id ligula consequat fringilla dignissim a sem. Duis eget
    risus vel est ullamcorper auctor. Aliquam vel ex in leo suscipit condimentum sed vitae leo. In porta eget augue eu porta. Pellentesque tellus eros, consequat vel aliquet id, consectetur a ante. Vestibulum sit amet ligula faucibus ligula auctor pretium
    non vel arcu.purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus Vivamus ut mi orci. Donec ut ipsum in nisl elementum posuere mollis id massa. Cras mattis felis est, a varius nisl euismod ac. Mauris cursus sed nulla
    in viverra. Duis maximus enim in vestibulum posuere. Nullam tempor, est in rutrum ullamcorper, purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus est. Nulla vel tortor id ligula consequat fringilla dignissim a sem.
    Duis eget risus vel est ullamcorper auctor. Aliquam vel ex in leo suscipit condimentum sed vitae leo. In porta eget augue eu porta. Pellentesque tellus eros, consequat vel aliquet id, consectetur a ante. Vestibulum sit amet ligula faucibus ligula
    auctor pretium non vel arcu.
    <br> purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus Vivamus ut mi orci. Donec ut ipsum in nisl elementum posuere mollis id massa. Cras mattis felis est, a varius nisl euismod ac. Mauris cursus sed nulla in viverra.
    Duis maximus enim in vestibulum posuere. Nullam tempor, est in rutrum ullamcorper, purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus est. Nulla vel tortor id ligula consequat fringilla dignissim a sem. Duis eget
    risus vel est ullamcorper auctor. Aliquam vel ex in leo suscipit condimentum sed vitae leo. In porta eget augue eu porta. Pellentesque tellus eros, consequat vel aliquet id, consectetur a ante. Vestibulum sit amet ligula faucibus ligula auctor pretium
    non vel arcu.
  </div>

</div>

<form id="MainForm">

  <label for="Name">Name: </label>
  <input type="text" id="Name" placeholder="e.g nirajan basnet" required/>

  <label for="Email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" id="Email" placeholder="sth@sthmail.com" required/>

  <label for="Comment">Your comment: </label>
  <br>
  <textarea maxlength="100" id="Comment" placeholder="What do you think about the site?"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline-block`:

```
#bodytext {

    display:inline-block;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things: First give css `overflow:hidden` to `#bodytext` and second after all 3 div i.e FirstParagraph , SecondParagraph ,ThirdParagraph you put `<div class="clear"></div>` and css for clear class `clear:both`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `float:left` in `#bodytext` div to resolve this issue, check snippet below..

```css
@font-face{
    font-family: "handlee";
    src : url("handlee.ttf");
}
@font-face{
    font-family:"berkshirestyle";
    src: url("berkshire.ttf");
}
body{

    background-image: url("glass.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;

}
#FirstHeader{
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    padding-left:100px;
    color:white;
    font-size: 70px;
    color: rgb(122, 38, 0);
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-family: handlee;
    font-style: italic;
}

#bodytext{
    padding: 30px;
    font-family: berkshirestyle, cursive;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #BCBCBC;
    float: left;
}



#bodytext{
    clear:left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid red;
    background-color: red;

}

#bodytext div{
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: left;

}


form{
    clear:both;

}
```

```html
<h1 id = "FirstHeader">Coffes here</h1>
<img src="coffee.png"  id = "Coffee" alt="coffee image" width="100" height="125"/>


<div id = "bodytext">

    <div id = "FirstParagraph">
        Duis maximus enim in vestibulum posuere. Nullam tempor, est in rutrum ullamcorper,
        Vivamus ut mi orci. Donec ut ipsum in nisl elementum posuere mollis id massa.
        Cras mattis felis est, a varius nisl euismod ac. Mauris cursus sed nulla in viverra.
        Duis maximus enim in vestibulum posuere. Nullam tempor, est in rutrum ullamcorper,
        purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus
        est. Nulla vel tortor id ligula consequat fringilla dignissim a sem. Duis eget risus vel
        est ullamcorper auctor. Aliquam vel ex in leo suscipit condimentum sed vitae leo. In porta
        eget augue eu porta. Pellentesque tellus eros, consequat vel aliquet id, consectetur a ante.
        Vestibulum sit amet ligula faucibus ligula auctor pretium non vel arcu.<br>
        purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus
        Vivamus ut mi orci. Donec ut ipsum in nisl elementum posuere mollis id massa.
        Cras mattis felis est, a varius nisl euismod ac. Mauris cursus sed nulla in viverra.
        Duis maximus enim in vestibulum posuere. Nullam tempor, est in rutrum ullamcorper,
        purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus
        est. Nulla vel tortor id ligula consequat fringilla dignissim a sem. Duis eget risus vel
        est ullamcorper auctor. Aliquam vel ex in leo suscipit condimentum sed vitae leo. In porta
        eget augue eu porta. Pellentesque tellus eros, consequat vel aliquet id, consectetur a ante.
        Vestibulum sit amet ligula faucibus ligula auctor pretium non vel arcu.purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus
        Vivamus ut mi orci. Donec ut ipsum in nisl elementum posuere mollis id massa.
        Cras mattis felis est, a varius nisl euismod ac. Mauris cursus sed nulla in viverra.
        Duis maximus enim in vestibulum posuere. Nullam tempor, est in rutrum ullamcorper,
        purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus
        est. Nulla vel tortor id ligula consequat fringilla dignissim a sem. Duis eget risus vel
        est ullamcorper auctor. Aliquam vel ex in leo suscipit condimentum sed vitae leo. In porta
        eget augue eu porta. Pellentesque tellus eros, consequat vel aliquet id, consectetur a ante.
        Vestibulum sit amet ligula faucibus ligula auctor pretium non vel arcu.
    </div>


    <div id = "SecondParagraph">
        purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus
        Vivamus ut mi orci. Donec ut ipsum in nisl elementum posuere mollis id massa.
        Cras mattis felis est, a varius nisl euismod ac. Mauris cursus sed nulla in viverra.
        Duis maximus enim in vestibulum posuere. Nullam tempor, est in rutrum ullamcorper,
        purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus
        est. Nulla vel tortor id ligula consequat fringilla dignissim a sem. Duis eget risus vel
        est ullamcorper auctor. Aliquam vel ex in leo suscipit condimentum sed vitae leo. In porta
        eget augue eu porta. Pellentesque tellus eros, consequat vel aliquet id, consectetur a ante.
        Vestibulum sit amet ligula faucibus ligula auctor pretium non vel arcu.
        <br/>
        purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus
        Vivamus ut mi orci. Donec ut ipsum in nisl elementum posuere mollis id massa.
        Cras mattis felis est, a varius nisl euismod ac. Mauris cursus sed nulla in viverra.
        Duis maximus enim in vestibulum posuere. Nullam tempor, est in rutrum ullamcorper,
        purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus
        est. Nulla vel tortor id ligula consequat fringilla dignissim a sem. Duis eget risus vel
        est ullamcorper auctor. Aliquam vel ex in leo suscipit condimentum sed vitae leo. In porta
        eget augue eu porta. Pellentesque tellus eros, consequat vel aliquet id, consectetur a ante.
        Vestibulum sit amet ligula faucibus ligula auctor pretium non vel arcu.purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus
        Vivamus ut mi orci. Donec ut ipsum in nisl elementum posuere mollis id massa.
        Cras mattis felis est, a varius nisl euismod ac. Mauris cursus sed nulla in viverra.
        Duis maximus enim in vestibulum posuere. Nullam tempor, est in rutrum ullamcorper,
        purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus
        est. Nulla vel tortor id ligula consequat fringilla dignissim a sem. Duis eget risus vel
        est ullamcorper auctor. Aliquam vel ex in leo suscipit condimentum sed vitae leo. In porta
        eget augue eu porta. Pellentesque tellus eros, consequat vel aliquet id, consectetur a ante.
        Vestibulum sit amet ligula faucibus ligula auctor pretium non vel arcu.
    </div>

    <div id = "ThirdParagraph">
        eget augue eu porta. Pellentesque tellus eros, consequat vel aliquet id, consectetur a ante.
        Vivamus ut mi orci. Donec ut ipsum in nisl elementum posuere mollis id massa.
        Cras mattis felis est, a varius nisl euismod ac. Mauris cursus sed nulla in viverra.
        Duis maximus enim in vestibulum posuere. Nullam tempor, est in rutrum ullamcorper,
        purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus
        est. Nulla vel tortor id ligula consequat fringilla dignissim a sem. Duis eget risus vel
        est ullamcorper auctor. Aliquam vel ex in leo suscipit condimentum sed vitae leo. In porta
        eget augue eu porta. Pellentesque tellus eros, consequat vel aliquet id, consectetur a ante.
        Vestibulum sit amet ligula faucibus ligula auctor pretium non vel arcu.purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus
        Vivamus ut mi orci. Donec ut ipsum in nisl elementum posuere mollis id massa.
        Cras mattis felis est, a varius nisl euismod ac. Mauris cursus sed nulla in viverra.
        Duis maximus enim in vestibulum posuere. Nullam tempor, est in rutrum ullamcorper,
        purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus
        est. Nulla vel tortor id ligula consequat fringilla dignissim a sem. Duis eget risus vel
        est ullamcorper auctor. Aliquam vel ex in leo suscipit condimentum sed vitae leo. In porta
        eget augue eu porta. Pellentesque tellus eros, consequat vel aliquet id, consectetur a ante.
        Vestibulum sit amet ligula faucibus ligula auctor pretium non vel arcu.
        <br>
        purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus
        Vivamus ut mi orci. Donec ut ipsum in nisl elementum posuere mollis id massa.
        Cras mattis felis est, a varius nisl euismod ac. Mauris cursus sed nulla in viverra.
        Duis maximus enim in vestibulum posuere. Nullam tempor, est in rutrum ullamcorper,
        purus purus sodales purus, sit amet imperdiet urna velit id velit. Proin vel dapibus
        est. Nulla vel tortor id ligula consequat fringilla dignissim a sem. Duis eget risus vel
        est ullamcorper auctor. Aliquam vel ex in leo suscipit condimentum sed vitae leo. In porta
        eget augue eu porta. Pellentesque tellus eros, consequat vel aliquet id, consectetur a ante.
        Vestibulum sit amet ligula faucibus ligula auctor pretium non vel arcu.
    </div>
</div>

<form id = "MainForm">

    <label for = "Name">Name: </label>
    <input type="text" id = "Name" placeholder = "e.g nirajan basnet" required/>

    <label for= "Email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id = "Email"  placeholder="sth@sthmail.com" required/>

    <label for = "Comment">Your comment: </label>
    <br>
    <textarea maxlength="100" id = "Comment" placeholder="What do you think about the site?"></textarea>
</form>
```